# Update a property on an object knowing only its name

Tags: c#

I have some public variables that are defined as follows:

```
public class FieldsToMonitor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Rev {get; set;}
}
```

I now want to populate those variable with values, but the `fm.[varible name]` needs be same as `field.Name`.  Here how I would populate in loop if I knew the property name ahead  of time and the order of the property name:

```
// loop 1
fm.Id = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value;

// ... loop 2 ...
fm.Title = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value;

// ... loop 3 ...
fm.Rev = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value;
```

Here is what I would like to do where `field.Name` can be substituted with property name:

- fm.ID becomes
  fm.[field.Name] where field.Name == "ID"
- fm.Title becomes
  fm.[field.Name] where field.Name == "Title"
- fm.Rev becomes
  fm.[field.Name]  and where field.Name == "Rev"

Is there a solution for this?

Here is more code of what I have so far:

```
public class FieldsToMonitor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Rev {get; set;}
}

static BindingList<FieldsToMonitor> FieldsToMonitorList
     = new BindingList<FieldsToMonitor>();
// ...

// Loop through the work item revisions
foreach (Revision revision in wi.Revisions)
{
    fm = new FieldsToMonitor();
    // Get values for the work item fields for each revision
    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
    foreach (Field field in wi.Fields)
    {
        fieldNameType = field.Name;
        switch (fieldNameType)
        {
            case "ID":
            case "Title":
            case "Rev":
                // the following doesn't work
                fm + ".[field.Name]" = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value; 
                fm[field.Name] = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value;
                row[field.Name] = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this ultimately in a UI? Are you using WinForms or WPF or neither?

Comment: Please mind the presentation of your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is all heavily dependent on how these values are being retrieved, and it is difficult to tell from your limited example if the values are strings or the correct type just boxed as an object.

That being said, the following could work (but is hardly efficient):

```
public static void SetValue<T>(T obj, string propertyName, object value)
{
    // these should be cached if possible
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

    pi.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, pi.PropertyType), null);
}
```

Used like:

```
SetValue(fm, field.Name, revision.Fields[field.Name].Value);
// or SetValue<FieldsToMonitor>(fm, ...);
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify T in your example?

Comment: @Baboon: depends on the C# version he's using.

Comment: @sixlettervariables When my property is of type datetime, I do get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  It seems like the pi is null.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @NickPatel: Sure, this method requires the property name to match exactly. If they do not match exactly you'll have to search the array returned by `type.GetProperties()`, maybe `type.GetProperties().Where(p => String.Compare(p.Name, fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure I understand you correctly but here is a try

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SetProperty(this object obj, string propName, object value)
    {
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
}
```

Usage like

```
Form f = new Form();
f.SetProperty("Text", "Form222");
```

Comment: Agreed, assuming his `value` is of the proper type. It is difficult to say given the limited example.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use reflection to accomplish that. Here's a short example:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo() { Num = 7 };

    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Num").GetValue(foo, null));
}
```